# parent total count playa conditional

Tags: playa, conditionals, advanced-conditionals

Hey I am trying to use conditionals with Playa. I can't seem to get the following code to work

```
{if {exp:playa:total_parents channel='listing'} > '0'}
        <section class="listing-cards">
            <div class="gen-wrap">
                <header class="section-header light">
                    <h1>Our Listings</h1>
                    <h2>{title}</h2>
                </header>
              {exp:playa:parents channel="listing" status="not closed" show_expired="no"}
                    {lv_listing_card}
              {/exp:playa:parents}
        </div>
        </div><!--gen-wrap-->
        </section><!--listings-->
        {/if}
```

I don't want to show the .listing-cards section if there are no results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First to make it clear did u use it in {channel:entries} loop if not you should , and if you want to use it outside {channel:entries} loop you must add entry_id param

I am test your code on my localhost and it's work fine.

I hope this will help you.

Regard's.

Comment: Ya I do have it in the channel entries loop. I am getting errors like:A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: User Warning

Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if {exp:playa:total_parents entry_id="24" channel='listing' var_prefix="playabiLo4d5X"}

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 2762

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure on the full context but the problem could very well be the quotation marks around the 0. If you're comparing against a number then you don't need quotation marks as that will convert it to a string and will never match:

```
{if {exp:playa:total_parents channel='listing'} > 0}
```

If that doesn't work then you can probably simplify things a bit as the Playa loop—as with the Channel:Entries loop—will by default output nothing if there are no matches made. Using this as an example:

```
{!-- Parent (The channel with the Playa field) --}
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
    <h3>Article Media</h3>
    <ul>
        {exp:playa:children field="article_photos"}

            {if count == 0}
                {!-- Show substitute content --}
            {/if}

            {!-- Otherwise show the child entries --}
            {!-- Default behaviour: Nothing shown if nothing matched --}
            <li><a href="{path={channel_short_name}/{url_title}}">{title}</a></li>

        {/exp:playa:children}
    </ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So you should be able to use the regular `count` tag to check for the existence of any child entries (related articles).

If you want an alternative way to check for any child entries then you can use:

```
{if "{playa_parent:total_children}" > 0}
  ...
{/if}
```

Where `playa_parent` is the name of your Playa field.